# Plotly,js - Y autoscale

Tags: plotly.js

I have a line chart. When I run it the chart is autoscalled on Y axis. Meaning it shows max and min data automatically. Let's say the chart shows one hour of data. So, xaxis.range = ['01/01/2020 12:00', '01/01/2020 01:00']. If I change xaxis.range to ['01/01/2020 12:30', '01/01/2020 01:00'] and then relayout the chart will it autoscale the Y axis to new min and max of data that falls between new X axis range?

Thanks

Here is an example:
[Pen](https://codepen.io/MZolotoy/pen/dyoeqxz)

and code:

```
var data = [
  {
    x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
    y: [1, 3, 6],
    type: 'scatter'
  }
];

var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, data);
myDiv.layout.xaxis.range = ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00'];
Plotly.relayout(myDiv, myDiv.layout);
```

Where I am trying changing the X range but even that is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of today it is not yet possible to autoscale the y axis based on the the data that is currently visible on the x axis. This has been discussed in a github issue here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1876#issuecomment-314913229

However, if you calculate the new min and max of the y axis yourself, you should be able to set it via the relayout method.

```js
const data = [
  {
    x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
    y: [1, 3, 6],
    type: 'scatter'
  }
];

const myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, data).then(() => {
  const xRange = ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00'];
  const yRange = [1, 3];
  Plotly.relayout(myDiv, {
    'xaxis.range': xRange,
    'yaxis.range': yRange
  });  
});
```

```html
<head>
 <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
 <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```